# Dynamically loaded DOM objects and submitting values

Tags: jquery, jsp, dom

I am dynamically adding DOM elements via a JSON call and then I submit the form to the server, the problem I am having is that I cannot find the newly created DOM objects in the map (HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap())

Is there a common practice for that problem?

I would really appreciate your help thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check:

- Are all your dynamically created objects placed inside the <form></form> tags?
- Do all the elements have the name="someFormElementName" attribute specified?

A quick way to check this (in Chrome at least) is to right-click on the dynamically created element and select "Inspect Element". This will show you the element that was generated and the HTML.

Other than that, the elements should be submitting ok. You can also check this by using the "Network" tab in Chrome's developer tools. (On mac: View -> Developer -> Developer Tools, not sure how to get there in Windows)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, yes they are all in form tags and have name attribute. The problem was that I needed to add the DOM objects using jquery then I was able to get the form data from server side. 

Like:

$("<input/>").attr({type: "text", id: formData.id, name: formData.id, value: formData.value}).appendTo("#div_"+formData.id);